# RegOpenKeyEx function returns access denied error code 5 for reg key path containing'{ }'

Tags: c++, registry

I am trying to call RegOpenKeyEx function on reg key path for an app with Read permission in registry. I tested the call with another Reg key without the '{ }' in path and that works.

What am I missing ?

**Edit**
I have also tried requesting different security descriptor: KEY_READ,  KEY_QUERY_VALUE. Adding code snippet below.
I receive a return code 5. I am able to read other RegKeys from the same process which don't have a {}(receive error code SUCCESS i.e. 0).

```
LONG retCode = ::RegOpenKeyExW(
        hKeyParent,
        subKey.c_str(),
        REG_NONE,
        STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ,
        &hKey);

    if (retCode != SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Close();

    m_hKey = hKey;

    _ASSERTE(retCode == SUCCESS);
    return retCode == SUCCESS; code here
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code and the registry key in question.  Otherwise, we'll just be taking pot shots in the dark (and when that happens, somebody might get hurt!). Cute emoji though.

Comment: There are tons of Registry keys that have `{ }` in their names (guids, etc). `RegOpenKeyEx()` requires that a key's name consist of only *printable* characters other than ```\```, and `{ }` certainly fit that restriction. `RegOpenKeyEx()` can open keys with `{ }` just fine, but Registry keys are securable objects, so an Access Denied error means the calling thread doesn't have the correct permissions to open the key, plain and simple.

Comment: Yes, there's no link between (supposed) cause and effect here, be careful about jumping to conclusions like that.

Comment: Thank you, Paul Sanders and Remy Lebeau. I have added the code snippet and some more details.

Comment: And the actual registry key you are trying to open is? (full path please).  Also, you can inspect the security attributes associated with any particular registry key in RegEdit (and that's what I'd recommend you do).

Comment: Reg-Key is for a third-party application Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{6G98233F-290C-6784-8099-2CC2C39*****}.  I checked the permissions on the key and READ is checked. All I need to do is check if this key exists, meaning if the app is installed.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Does that key permit read access to group 'Everyone'?  That's what you need (and open the key using `KEY_READ`).  Also, if you want me to see your next comment, please tag it with @paulsanders to alert me.  Thx.

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, the key permits access to 'Everyone'.

Comment: Hmmm.  Please post a [mre] and I'll try it here.  Please have that try to open a registry key that is likely to exist on all Windows machines (and check that you still get the error 5!).